# Setting up an A record for connecting domain to server

Tags: dns, namecheap

I have a web server set up at home for hosting a web site and I bought a domain from NameCheap. Now I want to connect the two together. I watched a lot of tutorials and I can see that the most popular way of registering your server is with a DNS 'A record' by connecting to my IP address. The problem is that my IP address is changing every once in a while and I am not sure if this means that I have to make my IP static. Is that possible and how do I do that? Also, is this a good way of connecting my domain to my server or is there a better way?

Comment: search for free dynamic dns

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, there are 2 options:

1. **Call your ISP**, and ask if they offer a static IP as an option for your service (depending on where you live, this could be expensive, and not available for home connections). Then point the DNS A to your new fix IP.
2. **Use a service like "No-IP"**: In this scenario you have to associate a CNAME (instead of a A Record) to a subdomain from No-IP, and they will redirect to your home dynamic IP.

Now take into account, for those 2 cases, you'll need to forward that domain to your local computer using the function of DDNS of your router, plus another settings like port forwarding.

Comment: Now, for any Real World application, I would recommend to rent a VPS or use a Cloud Provider. Having a service like this in your own home it's good for learning or hobby, but it's unreliable for a project with stakeholders, plus could bring some security risks to your home network (like a DDoS attack), and you'll be in charge of  adding redundancy to things like power or Internet Connection.